# AjaxSetup conflicting with jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I want to use `ajaxsetup` for all my ajax calls but it seems that it is interfering with my `jqgrids` on the site.  Is there a way to globally setup my ajax calls without it messing up `jqgrids` internal calls.  The below code is what i want to use on my ajax calls except the `jqgrids`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
```

Comment: By definition, global settings affect all uses of `$.ajax`, and jQgrid uses `$.ajax`.

Comment: Why don't you just write your own `myAjax()` function that calls `$.ajax` with those options added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the global defaults, write your own AJAX function that merges in your defaults and calls `$.ajax`. Then use this function instead of `$.ajax` in your code.

```
var myAjaxSettings = {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
};
function myAjax(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, options, myAjaxSettings);
    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

I've kept this definition simple, it doesn't accept all the different argument formats that `$.ajax` does, just the format where everything is in a single `options` object argument. You can get more elaborate if you want.

You use it just like `$.ajax`:

```
myAjax({
    url: "yourURL",
    data: {
        param1: value1,
        param2: value2
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: how would you use the myAjax function?